# Can not OAuth using Facebook iOS SDK Since February 6th

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook-graph-api, facebook-oauth, django-authentication

I have a question about Facebook OAuth.

Since Febrary 6th, I can not connect to Facebook in Developing iOS Apps.
Before,  I can do it.

And, I try to test Facebook sample apps addition of iOS SDK.
The BooleanOGSample of sample in iOS6.0, is able to connect to Facebook, But version iOS5.0 is not able to connect.

Maybe, ver 6.0 is used by 'FBUserSettingsViewController' in SDK, but ver 5.0 is connect by web page. 
But the web page 404.

How to connect to Facebook OAuth by iOS5.0, iOS5.1 ? 
the facebook sdk is 3.1.1 (release october 2012 )

Comment: Facebook made some changes taking place on Feb 6th.
Read here, perhaps your solution is here: https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/completed-changes/

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are using older sdk of facebook ,you shoudldownload newer versioin of the facebookSDK for iPhone and then try,If still you can not pass from Oauth then try to make a new application on developer.facebook.com .

Hope it will help you.

Comment: Thank you very much your answer, Kiti. But I just Download from Facebook Developer. so I think it is newest version